# It is possible to join more TFS changsets into one?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I made several terrible changesets, is it possible to join/group them to one changeset ? Because I would like to keep the meaningful and readable commit history.

[image]

Comment: You can edit the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is **not support** in TFVC. And there had been a feature request in uservocie called  [TFS to merge multiple, non-continuous changesets](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2638075-tfs-to-merge-multiple-non-continuous-changesets#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D) which has been **declined** by the PM of TFS.

> Thanks for the feedback on this idea. We have reviewed this feedback
>   and determined that we will **not be able to complete this
>   suggestion** in the foreseeable future.
>
> *Matt Mitrik  TFS Program Manager*
>
> *March 12 2015*

For your situation, you can either edit the comment just like *AakashM* suggested or try to use Visual Studio add-on [TFS Productivity Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/aefd1dfc-c9ef-4603-9565-9fc85944a7d2).

Moreover, about how to edit the changeset comment, please refer the answer in this question: [Edit changeset comment after updates have been checked in to TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245541/edit-changeset-comment-after-updates-have-been-checked-in-to-tfs)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean like a git "squash", I'm afraid not.